# Radio button checked attribute is not getting set to false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 buttons `yes` and `no`, and simply I am toggling them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <head>
         <title>Demo Project</title>
      </head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script src=""></script>
      <script>  
          function enableCheckBoxAndDisableNoRadioButton() {
             $(".checkbox").attr("checked",true);
             $("#no").attr("checked", false);
          }

          function disableCheckBoxAnddisableYesRadioButton() {
             $("#yes").attr("checked", false);
             $(".checkbox").attr("checked",false);
          }
      </script>
      <body>
         <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" >
         <p>yes <input id="yes" type="radio" onchange="enableCheckBoxAndDisableNoRadioButton()"></p>
         <p> no<input id="no" type="radio" checked=true onchange="disableCheckBoxAnddisableYesRadioButton()"></p>
      </body>
   </html>
```

When I click at `yes`, that time no button getting deselected and checkbox getting selected. 
But when I click at the `no` button, that time checkbox getting deselected but `yes` button is selected too. I want to make it deselect.

Let me know what is the problem.

I am running this code on chrome: 53.0.

Answer (score 5):

Use `prop` insted of `attr`.

```
function enableCheckBoxAndDisableNoRadioButton() {
    $(".checkbox").prop("checked", true);
    $("#no").prop("checked", false);
  }

  function disableCheckBoxAnddisableYesRadioButton() {
    $("#yes").prop("checked", false);
    $(".checkbox").prop("checked", false);

  }
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/s4t5crem/)

Answer (score 1):

in place of `attr`, i changed it to `.prop` and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

change **.attr** to **.prop** then it worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to check where we can use **`.prop()` / `.attr()`**

> Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` in the most of cases.

See some list of attributes and property  below:

```
| **Attribute/Property** | **Attribute**  | Property

| accesskey              |      Yes       |    No
| align                  |      Yes       |    No
| async                  |      Yes       |    Yes
| autofocus              |      Yes       |    Yes
| checked                |      Yes       |    Yes
| class                  |      Yes       |    No
| href                   |      Yes       |    No
| multiple               |      Yes       |    Yes
| readonly               |      Yes       |    Yes
```

and read more about [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)